# How to make web-server address into dns?

Tags: apache2, webserver

I'm using apache webserver on ubuntu base o/s. I want to change the web-server hostname to lets says xyz.compnayname.com.uk.

The virtual machine that runs the web-server is stand-alone machine not part of domain as my host machine which is windows 7. I want to know if by editing etc/hosts to

```
 ipaddress          xyz.companyname.com.uk
```

Would allow the users to access my web-server by dns? Like http://xyz.companyname.com.uk/whateverfile.

OR i need to make some changes into the apache configuration files too.

Thanks

Comment: Let me get this straight: you *do* own the domain name companyname.com.uk?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need one more thing, which is to make an entry in the apache virtual hosts configuration file.  It's pretty easy to do, once you see how it's done.

Normally, you would edit the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default`, which is a link to the default file in "sites-available."

In this file, you can add any number of virtual hosts, which define a site and its directory.  So, you would add an entry to the end of the file something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/whateverdirectory>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/whateverdirectory/
    ServerName xyz.companyname.com.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

In my configuration file, I have the initial "VirtualHost" definition set to the root `/var/www`, so I can access things that are not defined in the configuration file, like phpmyadmin (which could be defined, but isn't right now), etc.  I have a static index page there saying something more useful than "It works!".

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by @MartyFried is 100% true. In the way you can active with IP also.

> Don't forget port forward, otherwise, its not visible to WWW. You can use both of them.

```
Listen 172.20.30.40:80
Listen 172.20.30.40:8080
Listen 172.20.30.50:80
Listen 172.20.30.50:8080
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1-80
ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
DocumentRoot /www/example1-8080
ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2-80
ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50:8080>
DocumentRoot /www/example2-8080
ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```